# Phoenix - no route found for GET /static/js/some.js

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I am migrating my rails application to phoenix framework.

I added some javascript (say `some.js`) and css files to `web/static/js` and `web/static/css` dir.

`<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/some.js") %>` in the front page `page/index.html.eex`didn't work. It raised the exception (dev env):

```
Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError at GET /static/js/some.js
no route found for GET /static/js/some.js (VisualTrader.Router)
```

If I copied `some.js` to `priv/static/js` dir, it worked. So what I missed? I thought the assets pipeline worked like the one in rails, which auto precompiled resources.

Below list my phoenix framework environments:

- Elixir version

  ```
  elixir -v

  Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

  Elixir 1.3.0-dev (187f4f8)
  ```
- Phoenix version

  ```
  defp deps do
     [{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.2"},
     ...
  ```

Comment: Can you verify that the `priv/static/js/some.js` file exists? JS is developed in the web directory, but served from the priv directory. I've never used the built-in brunch, but AFAIK it should automatically compile/copy it over to priv.

Comment: @CodyPoll I touched `web/static/js/some.js` and the logging is 
`10 Mar 02:10:19 - info: compiled some.js and 7 cached files into app.js in 1 sec`. 

How can I keep the javascript files separated?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the Javascript File to be precompiled you'd need to add the following line of code.

Add your Javascript file in `web/static/js` directory.

In `web/static/js/app.js` include your file

```
import "./some-file"
```

Comment: I want to include a particular `js` inside a particular view template. So the whole pre- compilation thing becomes useless and needless.